# Getting _remove_dead_weakref error for LLDB

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, lldb

Everytime I launch lldb on MacOS, I'm getting the following error.

```
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

I checked that all the files and names were there.

I don't know what's causing this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you launching lldb? this looks like a non standard `Brew` install of things (Python at least) any reason you dont just install and use xcode which ships with command line utilities including lldb?

Comment: I'm just typing "lldb" into the terminal. So I need to launch with xcode? I was hoping that I can just use the terminal...

Comment: you can use lldb from the terminal, but it looks like youve gone about manually installing things with homebrew rather then simply installing xcode along with the xcode CLI tools which would work just fine from the terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python framework lldb uses actually comes with the system, not with Xcode, but other than that, Brad's onto it.

lldb links to Python, which it uses to power a bunch of extensibility features.  Even though lldb pulls in the Python dylib from the system install - because that's what it linked to - the presence of other Pythons (usually found because the other python binary is on your path ahead of /usr/bin/python) will cause Python to read its library files from the other Python install.  And that seems not to go well in general.

In most of the cases where we've seen this, making sure /usr/bin/python is frontmost on your path will solve the issue.  Also make sure PYTHONPATH doesn't refer to the python files in your side installation.

Comment: This seems to work.  If I run `rust-lldb`, I get the exception noted in the OP.  If I run `PATH=/usr/bin/ ~/.cargo/bin/rust-lldb`, things work.

Comment: So in case you want to keep a newer Python from Homebrew ahead of the system Python in your `PATH`, your best bet is to make your own `lldb` shell script wrapper and put it in `~/.local/bin` (and put `~/.local/bin` first in `PATH`)?

Answer (score 1):

To use the system Python for lldb but keep using Homebrew python for everything else, save this shell script as `~/.local/bin/lldb`:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset PYTHONPATH
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
exec lldb "$@"
```

Then `chmod +x ~/.local/bin/lldb` to make it executable. Make sure `~/.local/bin` is in your `PATH`, and comes before `/usr/bin` where the system `lldb` lives.

Comment: You should not need to use this trick with the most recent lldb either from TOT llvm.org or from Xcode 11 when it comes out.